# Wi-Fi PCMCIA card that is flush or some sort of adapter(s)

Tags: wifi, network-adapter

I have a Fujitsu P1620 ([CNET Review](http://www.cnet.com/products/fujitsu-lifebook-p1620/#!), 2008) that I want to add the [Broadcom Crystal HD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcom_Crystal_HD) ([Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00A66PCTM)) board to.  That means I have to re/move the mini PCIe Wi-Fi card.  The P1620 has a [PCMCIA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC_card) slot, so I've been looking into finding a flush Wi-Fi card where the antenna doesn't stick out.  The problem is, I can't seem to find one.

I am looking for a PCMCIA (aka CardBus) Wi-Fi adapter that meets the following criteria:

- Fits into a PCMCIA slot
- 2.4 GHz b/g/n support
- 150 Mbps
- flush with the edge of the slot, or very close to it
- Reasonably priced

  Windows support/drivers

**Nice to haves**

- 5 GHz support
- 300 Mbps
- Cheap
- Well supported on Linux
- Promiscuous mode

This [Ubiquiti](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004EHUVHW) on Amazon appears to fit the bill, but it's really expensive.  Which probably stems from its high end name.

Alternatively a series of parts and adapters (PCMCIA, Expresscard, mini PCIe, etc) to fit into the slot would be fine.  The Wi-Fi antenna is still in the chassis (could be reused), or I could run a new one in the chassis.

**USB PCMCIA + USB WiFi**

I would prefer to not use USB, but will do so as a last resort.  USB is supposedly heavy on the CPU and I don't know if I will have enough room/ports for a suitable USB adapter and card in the case.  If you think you can make it work, feel free to suggest that solution, but be detailed.

If I were to do something like this, I would want to modify the card adapter so the USB Wi-Fi adapter sat further in, and potentially rig up some form of external antenna or connector.

**Edits/additions**

[This](http://www.ebay.com/itm/BreezeCom-Breezenet-PCMCIA-SA-PCR-Wireless-802-11-LAN-Card-New-/351252445527?hash=item51c846f957:g:46UAAOSwnDxUijx9) would be a perfect form factor and antenna management system.  This particular card uses a different networking standard than is common today, so it won't work for my purposes.  This type of antennae seems popular for the cell cards, but I can't find any for Wi-Fi G or N.

A Wi-Fi version of [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Hidden-Inside-USB-2-0-Bluetooth-Wireless-to-PCMCIA-PC-Card-CardBus-Adapter-/251666257311?hash=item3a987a559f:g:COIAAOSwRLZULqWx) would be awesome.  Sadly, I was unable to locate one.

I snagged a cheap Ubiquiti (listed above) on eBay, but I would still like to hear other solutions.  The Ubiquiti seems to be [supported by Linux,](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/forums/showthread.php?t=10338) but I will have to engineer a protector for the antennae connectors, but that won't be too bad.

Comment: Something worth considering is Cardbus is essentially dead - and has been for quite a while, which may explain the lack of slots. Coulda sworn my thinkpad of the same era had express card rather than PCMCIA tho

Comment: I realize it's an older technology, but that's what I have.  It IS an older machine...